# MySQL query to perform pattern matching

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

In MySQL how to search a value in a field that contains value separated by commas?(I have to search for (5,6) and it should return the field that contains all possibilities {5,6,(5,6)}

Is it possible?

Comment: In the first table I have a column with values (5) (5,6) (1,5,6) and so on and then I am retrieving a value say (5,6) from that table and then perform matching in another table where the column contains values like (1,5)(2,6)(5,7)(6,8)(8,9,10) now I want the query to return (1,5)(2,6)(5,7)(6,8).thankx in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
MyModel.where("field LIKE (?)", "%5,6%")
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many methods in MySQL for pattern matching, such as `like` ,`RLIKE`, `MATCH-AGAINST`,`FIND_IN_SET`, etc. The exact one depends on your need. Explain your sample data and desired result; then I can say which function will best help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
MyModel.where("filed REGEXP '5,6'")
```